# jQuery or Javascript: Find HTML text by character offset and length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have some JSON:  `{"div_id":"pie1","str_offset":"5","str_length":"6"}`

And I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="pie1">I like pie!</div>
```

I want to be able to wrap a `<span>` element around the matching text, i.e., 6 text characters long starting 5 characters from the beginning of the text node.  So in this example it would wrap "e pie!".  Ideally, the solution would ignore the presence of any other tags, such as `I like <b>pie!</b>` and only count the text characters.

If a jQuery like selector is not feasible, it would be OK to just find the position of the str_offset, write the HTML, then find the end position and close the tag.

`

Comment: Select as in highlight, or select as in wrap?

Comment: I want to wrap it.  Edited for clarity.

Comment: Are there any other elements inside of there (like `I like <b>pie</b>`) or is it just plain text?

Comment: There could be other elements, but I don't want to include them in the character count.  Edited again for clarity. :)  Although I realize that could cause overlapping tags.

Comment: Try writing some code.  You'll want to extract the three parameters from the object first.  jQuery is the way to go.

Comment: Steve: I'm all set with how to extract the parameters.  I'm looking for help in targeting the range of text.  If you can point me to the best jQuery solution I'd be very grateful.

Comment: It's _easy_ if the div only contains plain text, but allowing for potentially multiple other elements as in `I <i>like <b>pie</b></i>` makes it more complicated, especially if you can't just rewrite the html contents because those child elements have event handlers that you need to retain. What should happen if the offset and/or string length specified are past the end of the div's actual contents?

Comment: Let's assume, for the sake of example, that the offset and length will never fall outside of the div.  If you could start me off with the easy version (without other elements) that would help too.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the simple example where we assume the div doesn't contain any child elements, you can do it something like this:

```
function wrapText(id, offset, length){
    $("#"+id).html(function(i,oldHtml) {
        return oldHtml.substr(0,offset) +
               "<span>" +
               oldHtml.substr(offset, length) +
               "</span>" +
               oldHtml.substr(offset + length);
    });
}
wrapText("pie1",5,6);   // obviously use values from your JSON here
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TfAAC/

When you call jQuery's [`.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) with a callback function jQuery calls your function with the current html text and you return the new value.

The following more complicated code "works" if there are child elements within the div, but it potentially creates overlapping tags when it inserts the span tags:

```
function wrapText(id, offset, length){
    $("#"+id).html(function(i,oldHtml) {
        var i, c, spanStart, spanStop;
        for (i = 0, c = 0; i < oldHtml.length; i++) {
            if (c === offset)
               spanStart = i;
            else if (c === offset+length) {
               spanStop = i;
               break;
            }
            if (oldHtml.charAt(i) === "<"){
               while (++i < oldHtml.length && oldHtml.charAt(i) != ">" && oldHtml.charAt(i+1) != "<");
            }else
               c++;
        }        
        if (spanStart === undefined)
           return oldHtml;
        if (spanStop === undefined)
           spanStop = oldHtml.length;
        return oldHtml.slice(0, spanStart) +
               "<span>" + oldHtml.slice(spanStart, spanStop) + "</span>" +
               oldHtml.slice(spanStop);
    });
}
```

You can see in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TfAAC/1/ that the html produced by the above has span tags in the "right" places, but when the browser actually displays it it doesn't like it (at least, Firefox doesn't) because of the overlaps.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff - If you are talking about the second piece of code, take a closer look at the second demo. Only one letter is coloured yellow because the html produced has overlapping tags and the browser doesn't like it. That's why my demo also included an `alert()` that shows what the actual html was - you can see the original `<b>` and `<i>` tags are retained. In a test that doesn't produce overlapping tags it is fine, but the OP said in a comment that he's aware this process might produce overlapping tags so I deliberately put that in the demo...

Comment: I see now. It creates invalid nested tags. You would have to add extra code to avoid that `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/5J93b/4/

Use `wrapText(elem, 5, 6);` to wrap six characters starting from position 5.

Use `wrapText(elem, elem.textContent.length - 6, 6);` to wrap the last six characters.

It will ignore HTML tags (side effect: no HTML tags will be present in the end).

Here is the code:

```
function wrapText(elem, start, length) {
    var before = elem.textContent.substr(0, start);
    var after = elem.textContent.substr(start + length, elem.textContent.length - length);
    var letters = elem.textContent.substr(start, length);
    elem.innerHTML = '';
    var text1=document.createTextNode(before);
    var text2=document.createElement('span');
    text2.style.backgroundColor='red';
    text2.innerHTML = letters;
    var text3=document.createTextNode(after);
    elem.appendChild(text1);
    elem.appendChild(text2);
    elem.appendChild(text3);
}
```